# Trying to delete a line in a text file -VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm very new to coding so any help is appreciated.

I've created a simple listbox that displays an array from a text file.
I wanted to add a textbox and a delete button so the user can type a word and then delete that line from the text file.

I've read many forums with various solutions for this but all have returned errors - currently I am getting this error: "System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\hches\source\repos\Inventory\Inventory\bin\Debug\Stock.txt' because it is being used by another process.'"

in sub DeleteLine()

Here is the relevant code to the Delete button and the respective DeleteLine() sub:

```
    Private Sub BTDel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTDel.Click

    Dim sr As New StreamReader("Stock.txt")

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim deleted As Boolean = False

    If TBSearch.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter an Item to Delete.")
    Else
        Do Until sr.Peek() = -1 Or deleted = True 'prevents it from looping through the whole stock if the item is deleted
            Dim Itm As String = sr.ReadLine()
            If Itm.Contains(TBSearch.Text) Or Itm.ToLower.Contains(TBSearch.Text.ToLower) Then 'if the line read from the text contains the search word, continue
                MsgBox(TBSearch.Text & " has been deleted.") 'simple messagebox says it has been deleted 
                DeleteLine()
                deleted = True
                TBSearch.Clear()
            ElseIf sr.Peek() = -1 Then 'if it reaches the end of the document and it hasn't been found
                MsgBox("Item has not been deleted.") 'message box appears saying it is not deleted
                deleted = False
                TBSearch.Clear()
            End If

            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub DeleteLine()
    Dim line As Integer = 0
    Dim Filename = "Stock.txt"
    Dim TheFileLines As New List(Of String)
    For line = 0 To TheFileLines.Count
        TheFileLines.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Filename))
        ' if line is beyond end of list then exit sub
        If line >= TheFileLines.Count Then Exit Sub
        TheFileLines.RemoveAt(line)
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Filename, TheFileLines.ToArray)
    Next
End Sub
```

Many thanks for any guidance,
Henry

SOLVED -- For anyone interested I will post my solution, thanks for the help.

```
    Public Sub DeleteLine()
    ArrayLoad() 'populates my array from text file
    File.Delete("Stock.txt") 'deletes original text file

    Dim stockList As List(Of String) = ItemNames.ToList 'creates a list using my array
    stockList.Remove(TBSearch.Text) 'removes the searched item from the list

    File.Create("Stock.txt").Dispose() 'creates a new text file (same name as the original so the program will work fine)
    Using sw As New StreamWriter("Stock.txt") 'sets up a streamwriter to write the new list to the text file
        For Each item As String In stockList
            sw.WriteLine(item)
        Next
        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Of course you have error because you already open file using `StreamReader`, you try to rewtite already opened file. There is one of the suggestions : simply load complete `Stock.txt` content into `List(Of String)`, perform desired deleting from that list and rewrite your file. The thing you do it in `DeleteLine()`.

Comment: @nelek Thank you very much, I will try this out now. I appreciate your help

Comment: Another option is to open a separate temp file and write all the lines (except the one to be deleted) to that.  Once done, close and delete the original, then rename the temp to the original named file.

Comment: @Idle_Mind That sounds like a good idea, I'll have a play with that too - thanks!!